# How to find database usage for a specific application action

Tags: sql-server-2014

A user is opening a page in our application which takes around 35 seconds.
I want to see what is happening in the database during this time. What's the best way to do this, doing a trace? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use SQL Profiler. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Best scenario is **only do this test** and not let anything else run
  on the server during the test.
- If not isolate one application server for this purpose so you can
  filter with host name or login (whatever is easier in your case).
- Set up an extended event trace with the events you want to capture,
  include necessary `Global Fields`.
- Set up data storage type `event_file` so you can review the result later and even load
  into a SQL Server database table.
- Since you are capturing the trace under one minute I would not bother to
  roll files.
- If you are not familiar with Extended Event trace search for 'getting
  started with extended events' and you will see a large amount of
  useful resources.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give it a shot. I can do this on a test server to isolate the action.